# iOS 8 VPN Services, changing server address

Tags: ios, xcode, nevpnmanager

Due to the terrible lack of documentation on the NEVPNManager, i'm going to state the question right here.

I've seen a couple of VPN apps working with server switching. It's like installing a basic VPN profile and allowing it to be updated. However i can't seem to find any information on doing this.

Could someone point me into the right direction? Simply updating the profile doesnt seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy,

Just override the config. It seems that after installing the certificate, you can use the same code as creating one, but then it will simply change the profile.

I wonder if more things have the same logic in Apple world :-)